# Highlighting text with angular filter complains about $sce unsafe even when using trustAsHtml

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, highlight

I am trying to highlight searched words by applying an angular filter on them that add span elements dynamically. I am trusting the html with `$sce` but I am still getting an error: `Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$sce/unsafe`

This is what I have (simplified):

html element:

```
<span ng-bind-html="entity.desc | filter:highlight(search)"></span>
```

directive:

```
scopePicker = ($sce) ->

    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        scope: {
            ...
        }
        templateUrl: 'my.html'
        link: (scope, element, attributes, controller) ->

            scope.highlight = (string) -> (desc) ->
                return trustAsHtml(desc) unless string
                return trustAsHtml(desc.replace(string, '<span class="highlighted">' + string + '</span>'))

            return
    }

angular
    .module('scopePicker')
    .directive('sScopePicker', ['$sce', scopePicker])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to use a filter function inside the scope. You need add it to the module level alongside the directive.

What I did:

```
highlightFilter = ($sce) -> (desc, string) ->
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(desc) unless string
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(desc.replace(string, '<span class="highlighted">' + string + '</span>'))

app = angular.module('scopePicker')
app.directive('sScopePicker', ['scopePickerService', '$q', scopePicker])
app.filter('highlight', ['$sce', highlightFilter])
```